# Database restore error

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I have a SQL Server backup file from another PC - I cannot change this file

When I try to restore, I get this error:

> *The database was backed up on a SQL Server running version 10.50.1600. That version is 
>   incompatible with this server, which is running version 10.00.2531. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to restore a database backed up on SQL Server 2008 R2 to a server that is running SQL Server 2008. You *can't* go backwards. You either need to upgrade the 10.00.2531 server to SQL Server 2008 R2, or you need to use the import/export wizard, SSIS, or a 3rd party tool to copy the schema/data over.

Comment: Get [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438).