# Using Visual Studio 2010, trying to link a database to the design. But it shows error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to connect them. It shows error:

> The database is version 782, VS 2010 supports version 655 and below.

What should I do in such situation?

Comment: If you want someone to help you, it would be useful to show what error you are getting. And possibly code. There's way too many possible errors for anyone to be able to reasonably help you. We can't guess what's wrong with it without more info!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633867/sql-server-version-655

Answer (score 1):

The error says that Visual Studio 2010 only supports [version 655](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html) and below, which is SQL Server 2008.

To me it sounds quite obvious, that you need a newer version of Visual Studio (or an older version of SQL Server).